# Need advice regarding VB.Net multithreading options

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, controls, richtextbox

Good day all,

I'm having a hell of a time figuring out which multithreading approach to utilize in my current work project. Since I've never written a multithreaded app in my life, this is all confusing and very overwhelming. Without further ado, here's my background story:

I've been assigned to take over work on a control application for a piece of test equipment in my companies R&D lab. The program has to be able to send and receive serial communications with three different devices semi-concurrently. The original program was written in VB 6 (no multithreading) and I did plan on just modding it to work with the newer products that need to be tested until it posed a safety hazard when the UI locked up due to excessive serial communications during a test. This resulted in part of the tester hardware blowing up, so I decided to try rewriting the app in VB.Net as I'm more comfortable with it to begin with and because I thought multithreading might help solve this problem.

My plan was to send commands to the other pieces of equipment from the main app thread and spin the receiving ends off into their own threads so that the main thread wouldn't lock up when timing is critical. However, I've yet to come to terms with my options. To add to my problems, I need to display the received communications in separate rich text boxes as they're received while the data from one particular device needs to be parsed by the main program, but only the text that results from the most current test (I need the text box to contain all received data though).

So far, I've investigated delegates, handling the threads myself, and just began looking into BackgroundWorkers.  I tried to use delegates earlier today, but couldn't figure out a way to update the text boxes. Would I need to use a call back function to do this since I can't do it in the body of the delegate function itself? The problem I see with handling threads myself is figuring out how to pass data back and forth between the thread and the rest of the program. BackgroundWorkers, as I said, I just started investigating so I'm not sure what to think about them yet.

I should also note that the plan was for the spawned threads to run continuously until somehow triggered to stop. Is this possible with any of the above options? Are there other options I haven't discovered yet?

Sorry for the length and the fact that I seem to ramble disjointed bits of info, but I'm on a tight deadline and stressed out to the point I can't think straight! Any advice/info/links is more than appreciated. I just need help weighing the options so I can pick a direction and move forward. Thanks to everybody who took the time to read this mess!

Comment: You blew up hardware with a serial port app?  Awesome!  +1 just for the fire risk!

Comment: Yeah, the tester receives serial commands to tell it to turn specific relays on and off. Well, one relay creates a hot short through a load bank and should only be actuated in intervals under a second. When the UI locked up, well, BOOM! ;-)

Comment: Windows is not a [real-time system](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/real-time/info), so you can write a multithreaded program that successfully passes every test you can come up with, but still is able to blow up things at a random pace ;)

Comment: Jacob, I'd suggest running your application with high CPU priority, but as @GSerg pointed out, you still can't guarantee your app will have time on the CPU.

Comment: What serial library are you using?  .NET's serial class creates threads on its own to handle the communications side, so you only need to worry about processing data and sending commands.

Comment: I am using .Net's serial class so it sounds like I'm good on that side of things, it's just the processing end that's kicking my butt! If it weren't for the fact that I need to parse the incoming data as soon as it's available (it controls some of the transitions of a state machine), I'd probably just be happy to do everything sequentially. If nothing else, I'd just like to be able to update the text boxes and a current test data buffer from a separate thread so that the main thread remains responsive...

Comment: @GSerg, yes, I agree. The ideal solution would be for me to modify the firmware of the tester itself so it'd take care of this matter on its own. However, I'm lacking access to the most recent code and the older code is missing key functionality I'd have to re-implement. Sadly, I don't have the time to do that so a hacked up solution will have to do for now. This is what happens when you work at a place that doesn't believe in version control and the only person working on the project suddenly dies. :-(

Comment: If you do this half-properly, you don't need to worry about CPU use.  A washing-machine controller could handle three serial ports, never mind a desktop PC with a multithreaded OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, serial ports, inter-thread comms, display stuff in GUI components like RichTextBox, need to parse incoming data quickly to decode the protocol and fire into a state-machine.

Are all three serial ports going to fire into the same 'processControl' state-machine?

If so, then you should probably do this by assembling event/data objects and queueing them to the state-machine run by one thread,(see BlockingCollection).  This is like hugely safer and easier to understand/debug than locking up the state-engine with a mutex.

Define a 'comms' class to hold data and carry it around the system. It should have a 'command' enum so that threads that get one can do the right thing by switching on the enum. An 'Event' member that can be set to whatever is used by the state-engine. A 'bool loadChar(char inChar)' that can have char-by-char data thrown into it and will return 'true' only if a complete, validated protocol-unit has been assembled, checked and parsed into data mambers. A 'string textify()' method that dumps info about the contained data in text form.  A general 'status' string to hold text stuff.  An 'errorMess' string and Exception member.

You probably get the idea - this comms class can transport anything around the system.  It's encapsulated so that a thread can use it's data and methods without reference to any other instance of comms - it does not need any locking.  It can be queued to work threads on a Blocking Collection and BeginInvoked to the GUI thread for displaying stuff.

In the serialPort objects, create a comms at startup and load a member with the serialPort instance. and, when the DataReceived event fires, get the data from the args a char at a time and fire into the comms.loadChar().  If the loadChar call returns true, queue the comms instance to the state-machine input BlockingCollection and then immediately create another comms and start loading up the new one with data.  Just keep doing that forever - loading up comms instances with chars until they have a validated protocol unit and queueing them to the state-machine.  It may be that each serial port has its own protocol - OK, so you may need three comms descendants that override the loadChar to correctly decode their own protocol.

In the state-machine thread, just take() comms objects from the input and do the state-engine thing, using the current state and the Event from the comms object. If the SM action routine decides to display something, BeginInvoke the comms to the GUI thread with the command set to 'displaySomeStuff'.  When the GUI thread gets the comms, it can case-switch on the command to decide what to display/whatever.

Anyway, that's how I build all my process-control type apps.  Data flows around the system in 'comms' object instances, no comms object is ever operated on by more than one thead at a time. It's all done by message-passing on either BlockingCollection, (or similar), queues or BeginInvoke() if going to the GUI thread.

The only locks are in the queues and so are encapsulated.  There are no explicit locks at all.  This means there can be no explicit deadlocks at all.  I do get headaches, but I don't get lockups.

Oh - don't go near 'Thread.Join()'.

Comment: Brilliant! Somebody please up vote this! I would if I had the reputation to do so. Good news is I have a very much watered down form of this right now so there shouldn't be too many problems with working in your concepts. Now if I can just get a handle on this threading business, I might be dangerous! Thanks a ton!

Comment: There are obviously some bits I missed out - nothing serious.  You will have to fill in the blanks.  If I get a chance, I'll edit in what I can think of later.